# link to namespace but removing the namespace from url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

Try to remove string from url:

```
resource :editor do
 resources :profiles
end
```

/editor/profiles

How would one remove the "editor" part from the url?

Answer (score 2):

Well you may not need to use nested routes in first place if you don't want editor part, but most important thing is what route you need for profile show page, i.e right now it must be like:

/editor/:editor_id/profiles/:id

If you don't need editor and its id over here too you should not use nested route over here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shallow routes

```
 resource :editor do
  resources :profiles, :shallow => true
 end
```

this way, you will be able to `/editor/:iditor_id/profiles` and `/profiles`